# How to delete dynamically added image from jssor slider with image id of slide

Tags: image, q, jssor

I have added images dynamically in jssor slider in asp.net.
I want to delete dynamically that from folder in which it is saved and entry from database also. I am not getting image id for deleting image. I am getting image index of selected side run time. When user click on delete link on screen, I want current slide image id to execute my delete functionality.

```
var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$("slider2_container", options);

var selected_index = jssor_slider2.$CurrentIndex;
```

Comment: You can specify id for each image.

Comment: @NIshant...could you share how you are to display the images after adding.
i am facing an issue where the slide is not happening...only the last uloaded image comes up on the slider.
take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744072/jssor-with-asp-net-dynamic-image