# JSSOR with ASP.NET dynamic image

Tags: sql, asp.net, slider, ashx, jssor

Here is my HTML Code that i am using

```
<div u="slides">
      <div>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Image FROM Gallery"></asp:SqlDataSource>
           <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="1">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <img u="image" src="<%# "image.ashx?Id="+ Eval("Id") %>" />
               </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
```

The Generic Handler .ashx for the image is [**THIS**](https://jsfiddle.net/fkjgah55/2/) 
My Issue is that on the Slide, only the last image uploaded come out.
For example, if i uploaded 5 images, only the fifth last uploaded image come up on the slider and it remains static.

I have tested the same generic Handler. it works normal for another slider.
am i missing something.

> P.S - the Jssor scripts and css are all in their default values.
>   nothing was edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed all images in a single slide.
Please create slide for every image as below.

```
<div u="slides">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Image FROM Gallery"></asp:SqlDataSource>
           <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="1">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <div>
                       <img u="image" src="<%# "image.ashx?Id="+ Eval("Id") %>" />
                   </div>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

Comment: @jssor Can you please help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808032/jssor-slider-disabledrag-not-working