# JSSOR slider $DisableDrag not working

Tags: jquery, jssor

I need to disable the dragging feature of the JSSOR slider. In their docs, I noticed that setting `$DisableDrag: true` will fix it but it didnt work.

[Here is the website](http://dev.cordbloodbanking.com/) where I am using this slider. Scroll down to the Patient Success Stories section to see the slider.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var options = {
    $FillMode: 2,                                       //[Optional] The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actual size, 5 contain for large image, actual size for small image, default value is 0
    $AutoPlay: false,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
    $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
    $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

    $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
    $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuint,          //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad
    $SlideDuration: 800,                               //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
    $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
    //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
    $SlideHeight: 534,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
    $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
    $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
    $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
    $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
    $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
    $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

    $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
        $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
        $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
        $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
        $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
    },

    $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                          //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
        $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                 //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
        $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
        $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
        $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $SpacingY: 8,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $Orientation: 1,                                //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
        $Scale: false,                                  //Scales bullets navigator or not while slider scale
    },
    $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 0,                               //0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $DisableDrag: true                             //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
    },

    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                           //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,                  //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
        $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
    }
};

var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
```

How do I fix this? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $DisableDrag is for thumbnail navigator.

To disable drag for slider, please set $DragOrientation to 0.

Comment: Thanks you! `$DisableDrag` was more intuitive so I was trying that. Thanks anyway.